# Angular : How do i bind value to a variable before i call a function

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

i am working on a rating system with ngb-rating, but when i rate the value isn't sent until the second call of the function,which means the function gets called before the value is getting binded!

i have tried to pass the binded value in the function argument but nothing changes

```
html:
 <ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate" max="5">
 <ng-template let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
 <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100" [class.bad]="index < 2" 
 (click)="evaluate(r.service.proprietaire.username)">&#9733;</span>
 </ng-template>
 </ngb-rating>
 <hr>
 <pre>evaluation: <b>{{currentRate}}</b></pre>
 typescript:   
export class MesReservationsComponent implements OnInit {
currentRate;

constructor(private evaluerUserService:EvaluerUserService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.mesReservations();
}

evaluate(partenaireId){
var note = this.currentRate;
this.evaluerUserService.evaluateUser(note,partenaireId).subscribe();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time making sense of what your asking. Can you please re-clarify?

Comment: simply i want to get the chosen value of currentRate (the binded value) and use it in the function but the event that calls the evaluate function ( (click) ) clearly runs before the one that binds the data to the variable: currentRate
P.S: sorry for my bad english

Comment: See the rating api https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/api. The event is (rateChange)="yourFunction($event)", not (click)="yourFunction()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is that you use the `rateChange` output:

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate" (rateChange)="evaluate(r.service.proprietaire.username, $event)" max="5">
    <ng-template let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
        <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100" [class.bad]="index < 2">&#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-rating>
<hr>
<pre>evaluation: <b>{{currentRate}}</b></pre>
```

And the new rate will now be passed into the `evaluate` method.

If, for whatever reason, you absolutely have to use a click, I would just put a timeout in your evaluate method:

```
evaluate(partenaireId){
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        var note = this.currentRate;
        this.evaluerUserService.evaluateUser(note,partenaireId).subscribe();
    });
}
```

This will give Bootstrap time to update the model value before you do your thing.

Comment: Sorry, Simon, the answer is not use window.setTimeout, it's use the event (rateChange)

Comment: ::glup:: sorry, I read so quickly. But you needn't use setTimeOut. StackoverFlow don't leve me restore the downvote, untiul your answer was edited

Comment: @Eliseo, updated my answer so that the more appropriate solution is first. Left the timeout solution there just in-case someone really needs to use the click event.